# What is the radius of a sphere given in the form $ \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 +z^2 = R \}$?

Tags: geometry, notation

Let $R > 0$. What is the radius of a sphere given in this format:

$$ \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 +z^2 = R \}$$

I used $R$ indicating the relation to the radius $r$ that I want to find. It might be trivial, but my mind still has difficulties understanding this type of notation hence an explanation would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Radius : $r=\sqrt{R}$.

Comment: Plug for the point $(r,0,0)$ on the sphere, you find directly $r^2=R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jean Marie wrote the radius of the sphere is $r = \sqrt{R}$.

Since your sphere is centered at the origin the answer lies really close at hand. The radius is just the length of any of the vectors on the surface and that length is given by the euclidian norm on $\mathbb{R}^3$ which is defined for any $v = (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$  exactly as

$$ \left\lVert v\right\rVert =\left\lVert (x,y,z)\right\rVert = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} = \sqrt{R}$$

where the last equality holds if $v$ lies on the surface of your sphere.

Answer (score 0):

In general, $$S = \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3: x^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2\}$$ is the equation of a sphere in $\Bbb R^3$ centered at the origin $(0,0,0)$ with radius $r$. In your case, $r^2 = R$, and so $r = \sqrt R$. $r = -\sqrt R$ is an algebraic possibility, but we throw this away because the radius of a sphere cannot possibly be negative!